# How constraint to first-order derivative in Lagrangian is a consequence of demand to get local theory?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, locality

In *Physics From Symmetry* Section 4.2 *Restriction,* the Author said that

> It is sometimes claimed that the constraint to first-order derivatives is a consequence of our demand to get a local theory, but this only rules out an infinite number of derivatives.

How one can reason that locality implies the restriction to first-order derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

As the quote said, you **cannot** conclude that the Lagrangian must involve only first order derivatives based on locality. What you cannot have is an *infinite* number of derivatives.

To give an explicit example:

Start from the *local* theory of 2 scalar fields

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2} (\partial \psi)^2 - \frac{1}{2} (\partial \phi)^2 - \frac{1}{2} M^2 \psi^2 - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi^2 + g \psi \phi^2
\end{equation}

Now we **integrate out** $\psi$ (in practice, we replace it by the formal solution of its equation of motion). The equation of motion for $\psi$ is
\begin{equation}
\left(\square + M^2\right) \psi = g \phi^2
\end{equation}
which has the formal solution
\begin{equation}
\psi = \frac{g\phi^2}{\square + M^2}
\end{equation}
Note that the operator $(\square + M^2)^{-1}$ actually involves an infinite number of derivatives:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{\square + M^2} = \frac{1}{M^2} \left(1 - \frac{\square}{M^2} + \frac{\square^2}{M^4} + \cdots \right)
\end{equation}
In fact this operator is non-local. The notation $(\square + M^2)^{-1} \psi$ is really just shorthand for a convolution with the Green's function
\begin{equation}
\frac{g\phi^2}{\square + M^2} = g \int {\rm d^4} y G(x,y) \phi^2(y)
\end{equation}
where $G(x,y)$ is the propagator associated with the Klein-Gordan operator for $\psi$. The Green's function is not a delta function, and so the integration over all of space is a non-local function of $\phi^2$.

If we plug this expression back into the original Lagrangian, we get
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{2} (\partial \phi)^2 - \frac{1}{2} m^2 \phi ^2 + \frac{g \phi^4}{\square + M^2} + ...
\end{equation}
This Lagrangian is a non-local function of $\phi$, because of the operator $(\square + M^2)^{-1}$.

Now in this case, the non-locality is "mild" in the sense that we know it actually descends from a local theory, and the non-locality is only an artifact of not working with all of the relevant degrees of freedom. However in general, if you write down a theory with an infinite number of derivatives, you aren't guaranteed to be able to introduce a new field so that the theory is local, so normally we require when writing Lagrangians for a local field theory that the Lagrangian is expressed in terms of a terms with a finite number of derivatives. (But this finite number can be larger than one).